# Url.Parameter for MvC routing for SHA2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not sure how I should ask the question, but I am trying to route a SHA1 encryption to be accepted by the ID.

**Example**

```
/Home/Index/Id
/Home/Index/A8-75-93-36-DA-4F-74-E1-E0-6B-78-98-DC-AE-FF-1F-17-CA
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the default route setup:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and then a controller action taking an `id` parameter:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and navigate to `/Home/Index/A8-75-93-36-DA-4F-74-E1-E0-6B-78-98-DC-AE-FF-1F-17-CA` the `Index` action of the `Home` controller will be invoked and the id parameter will be passed the hash value.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I actually made the parameter an "int" instead of a string so it didn't take it.